# Interference tensorflow with QWebEngineView

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyqt

I'm working on tensorflow-gpu1.12 (tensorboard 1.12.2) and PyQt (both 5.11.3 and 5.12.1) under Python3.6.7 (miniconda + pip), CUDA9.0, and cudnn v7 on a GPU-equipped windows10, 64bit PC (NVIDIA GeForce GTX1060). Tensorflow-gpu works with the NVIDIA GPU.

Under this condition, I failed in launching QWebEngineView together with importing tensorflow even in the attached short script. The window shows a black screen. Could anyone kindly suggest what the possible cause is?

I have another PC equipped with a NVIDIA GeForce GTX1070, and there is no problem with this PC. So the problem is machine- or configuration-dependent.

```py
# Everything works fine if the tensorflow import is commented out.
import tensorflow

import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
my_app = QApplication(sys.argv)
my_web = QWebEngineView()
my_web.load(QUrl("http://www.google.co.jp"))
my_web.show()
#
sys.exit(my_app.exec_())
```

Comment: try adding `sys.argv.append("--disable-gpu")` before `my_app = QApplication(sys.argv)`

Comment: Or try adding `sys.argv.append("--disable-gpu-blacklist")` before `my_app = QApplication(sys.argv)`

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! I tried both of them, but unfortunately the black screen still persists. Before the blackout, something appears at a moment..

Comment: Have you used both options or only one of them? I recommend you try only one of them.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried all the combinations, but it did not work.